# Unable to log out of clearance gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, clearance

I have recently move my project away from the somewhat bloat devise to clearance, though I am experiencing troubles when attempting to log out

I am currently get the error of the route not existing

```
No route matches [GET] "/sign_out"
```

routes

```
resources :passwords, controller: "clearance/passwords", only: [:create, :new]
  resource :session, controller: "clearance/sessions", only: [:create]

  resources :users, controller: "clearance/users", only: [:create] do
    resource :password,
      controller: "clearance/passwords",
      only: [:create, :edit, :update]
  end

  get "/sign_in" => "clearance/sessions#new", as: "sign_in"
  delete "/sign_out" => "clearance/sessions#destroy", as: "sign_out"
  get "/sign_up" => "clearance/users#new", as: "sign_up"

  constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedIn.new do
    root :to => 'shopping/merchants#index', as: :signed_in_root
  end

  constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedOut.new do
    root to: 'clearance/sessions#new'
  end
```

view

```
= link_to sign_out_path, method: :delete, class: 'mdl-navigation__link' do
    i.material-icons> exit_to_app
    = t('.log_out')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you there is not `get` route for `sign_out`, which is correct. You must do a `delete`. This means, despite your efforts with `method: :delete`, the link is executing a `get` request. There's something about your `link_to` that is not correct. It likely has to do with passing `method` while using the block form of link_to.

Try:

```
<%= button_to "Sign Out", sign_out_path, method: :delete %>
```

If that works, try:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", sign_out_path, method: :delete %>
```

If both of those work, then the issue is indeed with the way you're using the block form of the `link_to` helper and has nothing to do with Clearance.

Comment: Hi @derek do you have any solution that will resolve this issue

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane: updated with some things to try.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd follow up on this with a little more insights for anyone who found themselves here still wondering exactly what is behind this.

As suggested by Derek, to get this sorted, you'll need to use the **`button_to`** instead of `link_to`, as follows:

```
<%= button_to "Sign Out", sign_out_path, method: :delete %>
```

**Why can't I just use `link_to`?**

So more insights into this are delivered [by this previous SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095460/delete-links-stopped-working-data-method-delete-but-goes-to-show-page). Essentially, you can't make a link operate as a **DELETE** method, only **GET**.

If you have a look at how `link_to` is actually rendered in HTML on the page (after Ruby works its magic), you'll see the following:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/sign_out">Sign out</a>
```

And it's clear that `data-method="delete"` is still not going to cut it, and still runs the request as **`GET`**.

**But I don't want a button, I want a link?**

Your best bet is to look at some CSS on the element to get it back to looking like a link, otherwise, you'll need to go the Javascript route.

**Non-RESTFUL Clearance Centric Dirty Hack - Not Advised!**

Using `link_to`, change your `routes.rb` where the clearance route currently says:

```
  delete     "/sign_out" => "clearance/sessions#destroy", as: "sign_out"
```

to:

```
  get     "/sign_out" => "clearance/sessions#destroy", as: "sign_out"
```

It'll route the `GET` request to the `destroy` action on the Clerance controller. I dare say this is not advised and Derek could support why this was not supported in the first place (Devise gem does support this dirty hack)